# Removing nested LaTeX `\index`es

Tags: indexing, nesting

How would I, such as with regex and `sed`, remove all `\index` tags that occur inside any `\index` tags?

For example, a nested mess like this:

```
\index{Test\index{test\index{test}}ing One\index{one} Two\index{two} Three\index{three}}
```

would turn into

```
\index{Testing One Two Three}
```

I have complicated nested `\index`es like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\makeatletter
\let\oldtheindex\theindex
\renewcommand{\theindex}{%
  \oldtheindex%
  \let\index\@gobble}% Remove \index functionality
\makeatother

\begin{document}

a person\index{a person}\footnote{A. Person\index{a person}, \textit{On A. Person\index{a person!\textsc{some journal} or \textsc{His Papers\index{a person!\textit{His Papers}}of A. Person}!\textit{On His Papers}}\index{some other person}'s Lines of Force}, here's some lorem ipsum text (\textsc{Prestigious Journal}, vol. 10, part 1, pp. 27 to 83. — \textsc{His Papers\index{a person!\textit{His Papers}}of A. Person\index{a person}}, vol. 1, pp. 156 to 219; New York, 2005).}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

Yet, I get this error.

```
\\->\let \reserved@e                                                                          
                     \relax \let \reserved@f \relax \@ifstar {\let \reserved...               
l.14 ... vol. 1, pp. 156 to 219; New York, 2005).}
```

Why?

Comment: Are you asking how to remove this in your code (via something like `sed`) or just in the output?

Comment: Either; whatever works. Currently, such a nesting of `\index` tags causes `pdflatex` to throw errors.

Comment: Did you try: `\index{\begingroup\renewcommand\index[1]{}Test\index{test}...\endgroup}`?

Comment: @nicolai.rostov: No, because that's complicating things. I really don't want to index whatever is already inside an `\index`, unless that's possible. Is it?

Comment: @Geremia: oh, I see. What is your text editor? In Vim, it's not that complicated.

Comment: @nicolai.rostov: Vim, Emacs. I have them all.

Comment: I'm asking why the `\index` commands are nested, to begin with.

Comment: @egreg: Because I used `sed` to search and replace terms that I want indexed. Should `pdflatex` be throwing errors for nested `\index`es in the first place?

Comment: @Geremia I don't think that you should do a simple search and replace; in general, the index should point to the first  occurrence of the term or the main occurrences, not to all of them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can nullify the macro `\index` when inside the `theindex` environment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\makeatletter
\let\oldtheindex\theindex
\renewcommand{\theindex}{%
  \oldtheindex%
  \let\index\@gobble}% Remove \index functionality
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\index{Test\index{test\index{test}}ing One\index{one} Two\index{two} Three\index{three}}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

Here's a rundown of the problem:

1. Compile the above file, which writes an `.idx` file containing:

   ```
   \indexentry{Test\index{test\index{test}}ing One\index{one} Two\index{two} Three\index{three}}{1}
   ```
2. Run `makeindex` on this file, and it creates a `.ind` file containing:

   ```
   \begin{theindex}

     \item Test\index{test\index{test}}ing One\index{one} Two\index{two} Three\index{three}, 
           1

   \end{theindex}
   ```
3. Now compile the original file, which creates a new host of `\index` entries within the `.ind`, thereby making the new `.idx` resemble:

   ```
   \indexentry{Test\index{test\index{test}}ing One\index{one} Two\index{two} Three\index{three}}{1}
   \indexentry{test\index{test}}{1}
   \indexentry{one}{1}
   \indexentry{two}{1}
   \indexentry{three}{1}
   ```
4. ...and so forth until all `\index` entries have been resolved.

The solution intervenes at the start of the `theindex` environment and removes any further functionality of `\index`. Since `\begin{theindex}`...`\end{theindex}` forms a group, the change to `\index` is local.

---

Based on your updated post, I would suggest removing nested `\index`es at the call to `\index` by using the following definition:

```
\makeatletter
\let\oldindex\index
\renewcommand{\index}[1]{{%
  \let\index\@gobble%
  \oldindex{#1}%
}}
\maketother
```

Note that your way of using an index is not very effective. When you're using formatting commands within the index, the sorting is not correct. See the [`makeindex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/makeindex) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/indexing/makeindex/doc/makeindex.pdf) on how to place entries with a different formatting yet still maintain the appropriate sorting (see the `@` symbol).

Here is a complete MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\makeatletter
\let\oldindex\index
\renewcommand{\index}[1]{{%
  \let\index\@gobble%
  \oldindex{#1}%
}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

a person%
\index{a person}% First entry
\footnote{A. Person%
  \index{a person}% Second entry
  , \textit{On A. Person%
    \index{a person!\textsc{some journal} or \textsc{His Papers\index{a person!\textit{His Papers}}of A. Person}!\textit{On His Papers}}% Third entry
    \index{some other person}% Fourth entry
    's Lines of Force}, here's some lorem ipsum text (\textsc{Prestigious Journal}, vol. 10, part 1, pp. 27 to 83. — \textsc{His Papers%
    \index{a person!\textit{His Papers}}% Fifth entry
    of A. Person%
    \index{a person}% Sixth entry
    }, vol. 1, pp. 156 to 219; New York, 2005).%
  }

\printindex

\end{document}
```

with the `.idx` showing the six marked entries:

```
\indexentry{a person}{1}
\indexentry{a person}{1}
\indexentry{a person!\textsc  {some journal} or \textsc  {His Papersof A. Person}!\textit  {On His Papers}}{1}
\indexentry{some other person}{1}
\indexentry{a person!\textit  {His Papers}}{1}
\indexentry{a person}{1}
```

Comment: @Geremia: I don't understand what you mean by "type".